# Best Ajax Search/Filter

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am looking for the best way to mimic the facebook friend window, where you can use ajax to filter what you type and update it.

Any suggestions?
I was playing with flexgrid but I think that's overkill

Comment: Which friend window? The popup window when you try to search your friend's friends?

Comment: Yes, where you search by name it just filters the results, It's probably simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what your looking for:

I've had some success using this in an app:
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/